# Writing multiple lines to a file in TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm looking to modify gpsfeed+ to add in a section which writes the NAV string out to a text file while the simulator is running.  The tool is written in tcl and I'm at a loss as to what I need to do.  What I have so far is:

```
if {$prefs(udp) & $::udpOn} {
    # opens file to write strings to
    set fp [open "input_NAV.txt" w+]
    # one sentence per udp packet
    foreach line [split $::out \n] {    
    puts $fp $line
    }
    close $fp
}
```

Right now if UDP broadcast is switched on, I want to take each NAV string broadcast over UDP and write it to a file.  But the code above only writes 1 of the strings and then overwrites the string.  I've been trying to add in a /n switch, but I've not had any joy.

Answer (score 2):

I was using the wrong mode for opening the file:
   *w+   Open  the  file for reading and writing.  Truncate it if it exists.  If it does not exist, create a new file.*

I should have been using either of the following:

*a    Open the file for writing only.  If the file does not exist, create a new empty file.  Set the file pointer to the end of the file prior to each write.*

*a+   Open  the file for reading and writing.  If the file does not exist, create a new empty file.  Set the initial access position  to the end of the file.*

Comment: `r+` might also be appropriate; `a+` has (an approximation of) append-only semantics when writing.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a comment, but formatting.

This code:

```
foreach line [split $::out \n] {    
puts $fp $line
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
puts $fp $::out
```